# embedded_svc.menu.settings.directToButtonRouting Possible?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, liveagent, servicecloud, lightning-message-channel

I have used the following code before for Live Chat and it's working fine to direct to a button ID based on the Pre chat question customer answers. Now, this code seems to be not working when I started using the new 'Channel Menu'. Has anyone found a solution to direct to button routing if use a channel menu?

```
embedded_svc.settings.directToButtonRouting = function(prechatFormData) {
          if (prechatFormData[3].value === 'English') 
            return 'XXXX000000XYYY';
          if (prechatFormData[3].value === 'Spanish') 
            return 'XXXXX000000XAAA';
          if (prechatFormData[3].value === 'French') 
            return 'XXXX000000XBBB';
    };
```

Comment: By not working, are you seeing any error ?

Comment: @swetha Yes, I was getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'directToButtonRouting')
    at initESW". And I was getting this only for Channel Menu code

Comment: Does my answer on https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=9062I000000Bl36 help?

Comment: @Swetha, Thanks for that. But, is there a way we can pass the pre chat data to Transcript object when using "Channel Menu"'s Live Chat?